# Check value in loop

Tags: ruby

I'm iterating through an array:

```
  @fileArray.each() {
    |x|

  }
```

How can I access the value `x` to check if it begins with a specific string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick!

```
test = ['abc', 'bcabcef', 'abcdef']

test.each do |x| 
  if x.match(/^abc/)
    puts x
  end 
end
```

Outputs:

```
abc
abcdef
```

Answer (score 8):

```
test = ['abc', 'bcef', 'abcdef']

p test.select{|word| word.start_with?('abc')}
#=> ["abc", "abcdef"]
# or the very short:
test.grep(/^abc/)
#=> ["abc", "abcdef"]
```

Comment: +1 for start_with?  I'll have to remember that one.  It would be helpful for future readers if you added the documentation source for that method.  (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-select).

```
["a","ab","b","ac","c"].select{|x| x[0] == "a"}
 => ["a", "ab", "ac"]
```

If not, then you can just do

```
x[0..5] == "String"
```